# Pass parameter to function(e)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am terrible with JS and I need to use a nice button that I got from here: http://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/lEuLD/

In short, in HTML, I have:

```
<button data-label="click here!"></button>
```

and in scripts:

```
var loading = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.classList.add('loading');
    e.target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function () {
        e.target.classList.remove('loading');
        e.target.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 1500);
};


var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = btns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', loading);
}
```

I understand that when the page loads, an event listener gets added and function(e) gets executed on click. What I need is to be able to call another function and pass a parameter to it after function (e) gets executed which will do the real work. How can I do that?

In other words, without having the fancy button, I would normally be able to call a function by using:

```
<button onclick="functionName(id)"; data-label="click here!"></button>
```

I need to be able to call the function functionName(id) after the fancy button stuff do its work!

I know this might be very simple but I still could not do it.

thanks!

Comment: Add it at the end of the loading function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add it after the `click` callback has finished:

```
var loading = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.classList.add('loading');
    e.target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function () {
        e.target.classList.remove('loading');
        e.target.removeAttribute('disabled');

        functionName(); //CALL YOU FUNCTION HERE
    }, 1500);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed. I was dding it after "...1500);" :/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects to events handler.

Here is example on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/csLhymtz/

```
function MyObject (myTextArgument) {
    this.myTextArgument = myTextArgument;
}

MyObject.prototype.handleEvent = function (event) {
    if (event.type === "click") {
        this.clickHandler();
    }
}

MyObject.prototype.clickHandler = function () {
    alert(this.myTextArgument);
}

var myObject = new MyObject ("i have been clicked");
var hello = new MyObject ("hello world");

$("#myButton")[0].addEventListener("click", myObject, false);
$("#secondButton")[0].addEventListener("click", hello, false);
```

You can attach a handler to a button and as second argument pass a JavaScriptObject.

Such object will then have passed events to function called handleEvent.

There you can check what type of event you got, and depending on that execute proper event handler. You can create object with all arguments which you need and get access to them on events.

Comment: seems an over the top solution when the question was effectivly "where do I call a function when the previous one has finished"

Comment: Oh, well, was too much focused on passing arguments, to event handlers.